# Getting the Html5 canvas context data after drawing

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to get the context information before drawing onto the canvas. I am using common variables for multiple canvases to drawimage. So, before drawing image into the canvas. I want to get the data of previous drawing on it!

i.e,

I want to get the x,y coordinates and width,height of the drawing!

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done. you can't get these things after drawing!